# IMPORTXML Google Sheets Query HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using the `IMPORTXML` function on google sheets to import the latest visa numbers from the Canadian government however I can import everything on the web page apart from the data/numbers which I think could be down to `JavaScript`.

I simply just need to find a way to pull that data into the spreadsheet but I'm not experienced with JS.

Here's the [website](https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/work/iec/selections.asp?country=au&cat=wh) and here's my query:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/work/iec/selections.asp?country=au&cat=wh",
"//div[@class='col-md-8']")
```

Here is an [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n5DmvthX3-7ijf3kUKdI2oPP7WJR6gjtXhAZz9PVbtI/edit#gid=0).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Google Sheet's formula `IMPORTXML` is only able to read the static HTML source of the page so it will not be able to read any dynamically inserted element (as you guessed the visa number is dynamically inserted with a Javascript script).

If you inspect in your browser the page source of this site, you will see that the numbers like *Candidates in the pool* are not there and therefore, `IMPORTXML` will not be able to reach them.

In order to get them you will need to look for another web scraping technique (with libraries like [scrappy](https://scrapy.org/) and so on).

Comment: That's great, much appreciated. Most of them require some level of knowledge with coding. Do you know of any other way to either make the text static or even download an image/screenshot?

Comment: Maybe try using [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) with Apps Script.